# Need image of BIOS screen for Lenovo IdeaPad S300

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, bios

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad S300 laptop with a broken screen. The only way I can use it is with an external monitor. (Aside from the screen, it works 100%.)

Recently I've installed the Catalyst driver for my AMD graphics card;
now my HDMI monitor stopped working. (Yes, I've tried F10.)

Can someone please take a picture of his/her BIOS of this specific computer so I can navigate there blindly and disable the graphics card? I need a photo of only one screen where this option is.

Comment: In my laptop, there are 2 graphic cards, one which is baked in into my motherboard and a GTM 740m. Whenever I don't have the charger in my laptop, it uses the baked in graphical card. Is this an option? Edit: with no charger in you're laptop, you can't access the BIOS (in my case apperently)

Comment: thanks, but tried booting on battery power, still the same, i can even hear windows login sound, no video whatsoever...

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, installing drivers on windows should still let you see the boot sequence...

Try this:

Remove the battery from the motherboard a few seconds.

[image]

This will force to load the default setting of the bios setup.

Comment: I have notebook not PC, I dont see any battery like that when I open it...